# How can I query to mysql with ARRAY in condition

Tags: php, mysql

A have names of rows in array

```
$arr = array(fir, seco, third);
```

how can I query mysql like:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM $table where fir=0 and seco=0 and third=0";
```

but using array.

and

```
$query = "update $table SET fir='$ma', seco='$ma', third='$ma'";
```

but using array.

Comment: What is wrong with your current query?

Comment: You said "names of rows", but your query is using them as names of _columns_. Which is it?

Answer (score 1):

For search you can fire below query -

```
$str = implode(",", $arr);
$query = "SELECT * FROM $table where 0 IN ($str)";
```

But for update you have to use query what you have written.

Comment: I think you mean `implode`, and the IN clause would select any row that has a 0 in any of the three columns, and not only the ones with all 0's.

Comment: could have been an acceptable answer if only `implode` is used

Comment: Still not correct though.  OP is looking for rows where each column is equal to 0.  You could use the imploded string with this SQL statement: `SELECT * FROM $table WHERE ($str) = (0,0,0)`. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/70023/27

Answer (score 0):

easy,

```
$arr = array(fir, seco, third);

for(int i = 0;i<arr.lenght;i++)
{
$query = $query + " and "  + arr[i] + "=" + $ma;
}
```

Comment: This is PHP. You used mix of PHP and Javascript. This is not easy :)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do...

```
$fir = $arr[0];
$seco = $arr[1];
$third = $arr[2];
$query = "UPDATE $table SET $fir = '$ma', $seco = '$ma', $third = '$ma'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a more optimal answer, but you could use a for loop to create the SQL statement:

```
<?php
$arr = array(fir, seco, third);

$query = "SELECT * FROM $table where ";
$count = count($arr);
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
  $query .= ($i==$count-1) ? "$arr[$i]=0" : "$arr[$i]=0 and ";
}

echo $query;
?>
```

Echoes `SELECT * FROM $table where fir=0 and seco=0 and third=0`.  You can do the same with the `UPDATE` SQL statement.

### Update

Also, you could implode the array, like in Suresh Kamrushi's answer, and use the following code:

```
<?php
    $arr = array(fir, seco, third);
    $str = implode(',',$arr);
    $query_one = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE ($str) = (0,0,0)";
    echo $query_one;
?>
```

The UPDATE query would still need a for loop though, I think.